# Отображение элементов при наведении мышки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю проект онлайн словаря, возникла такая задачка, нужно чтобы при наведении на ссылку `foundword`, рядом с этой ссылкой отображались `countryflags`, сами же countryflags отображаются если в базе есть перевод слова на том или ином языке, в нашем случае это русский, английский и турецкий. К примеру, если к определенному слову нет перевода на русском, не будет отображаться российский флаг. По умолчанию, все флаги не отображаются вовсе, как уже было сказано выше, нужно чтобы флаги выводились именно при наведении мышки определенное на слово.

```
    <li class="listofwords">
          <a class="foundword" href="{% url 'translations' words.id %}">{{ words.title }}</a>
                <span id="flags">
                    {% if words.russian %}<img class="countryflags" src="{% static 'images/RU.png' %}" alt="RUS">{% endif %}
                    {% if words.english %}<img class="countryflags" src="{% static 'images/GB.png' %}" alt="ENG">{% endif %}
                    {% if words.turkish %}<img class="countryflags" src="{% static 'images/TR.png' %}" alt="TUR">{% endif %}
                </span>
            </li>
```

На одном из сайтов нашел приведенный ниже код, добавил туда свои селекторы, но результат не оправдал ожиданий. Делаю проект на Django, не могу понять в чем проблема, возможно какая не состыковка между тегами Django и jQuery. Сам я не js программист, но попробовал адаптировать js код, не вышло, поэтому обращаюсь к вам, коллеги.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.foundword').on('mouseover', function (event) {
            $(this).find('#flags').show();
        });

        $('.foundword').on('mouseout', function (event) {
            $(this).find('#flags').stop().hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
#flags {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: у Вас же `id=flags`, стало быть и не надо `this`. Просто `$('#flags').show() / hide()`

Comment: `$('.foundword').on('mouseover', function (event) {
            $('#flags').show();
        });

        $('.foundword').on('mouseout', function (event) {
            $('#flags').hide();
        });`
Вот так? Все равно не работает..

Comment: Может в консоли чето пишут? jquery-то подключен?

Comment: так у Вас же `span` не входит в ссылку. Не заметил.

Comment: Да, подключен. В консоли пусто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас `span` находится за пределами ссылки, соответственно тут самое оно будет использовать `next()`

```
  $( ".foundword" )
      .mouseover(function() {
        $( this ).next( "span" ).show();
    })
      .mouseout(function() {
        $( this ).next( "span" ).hide();
    });
```

Конструкцией `$(this).find('#flags')` Вы пытались найти элементы с `id="flags"` **внутри** `<a href="">..</a>`

Comment: Отлично! Все как надо) Благодарю! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Заменяем 
$(this).find('#flags');
// на
$(this).siblings('#flags');
```

> Сам я не js программист

Но вам не нужно напоминать, что в пределах одной страницы, не может быть два и более элемента с одинаковым id ;)

Comment: В приведенном html коде вроде только один элемент, у которого есть id :) Если я правильно я вас понял)

Comment: @AstemirBoziev, Я исходил из простой логики: если вы ищите элемент отталкиваясь от того элемента, на котором сработало событие, то возможно, что таких групп элементов у вас несколько. Иначе, можно было сделать просто `$('#flags').show();`, т.к. это единственный элемент.

Comment: Ок, спасибо! :)